# Args and dictionary in render_to_response

Tags: python, django

How to pass arguments and a dictionary in the query ?

My example does not work

```
return render_to_response('bookmarks_add.html', {'categories': categories, 'args':args})
```

Separately work

```
return render_to_response('bookmarks_add.html', args)
```

and

```
return render_to_response('bookmarks_add.html', {'categories': categories})
```

Comment: What does `args` contain?

Comment: what do you mean by does not work ? in your initial attempt, what makes you believe it is not working as desired ? May be the issue is the way you are consuming the data available in the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
args.update({
   'categories': categories,
})
return render_to_response('bookmarks_add.html', args)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I need!